# how to lookup multiple items from one list to another and the connect results into a string

Tags: list, lookup-column, item, workflow-lookup

I have list "A" in which i store `name`, `email` and `product`.

I have a list "B" which should trigger an email based on some values. One of these values is `product`. If I chose "car", the workflow should then look into list "A" and see which email addresses store the same product. So if user X with email x@g.com has a product "car", it should send an email to his address. The problem is that this works only if there's just one person with a car. List A has multiple people with the same product. I somehow need to join all the mails into one or multiple emails and send them an email.

Something like an filter for product and return all emails that match that filter... any ideas?

I use sharepoint 2016, also infopath 2013 or SPD, but workflow 2010 (hope its not an issue)

cheers

ML

Comment: Are you absolutely not able to use 2013 workflows?  It would make what you are trying to do so much easier.

Comment: i think your solution will return only one name, i need a solution that will return all where "car" is written

Comment: have you tried my answer, did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

SPD workflows do not have any looping capability.  It is going to find the first one that has "car" in it and execute the workflow.  You will have to incorporate some type of trigger on each list item and loop through it with code to trigger a workflow on each item in list B that has the product you are looking for and send the email.  You can accomplish this with jQuery or RESTful type calls.  I hope I am understanding what you are trying to do.  You will have to work in a programmatic loop to trigger the workflows for each product in the secondary list you are trying to email to.  You will more than likely have to put in some other hidden fields to use as flags for your workflow triggers.  Use your code to change the email flags on your lists and then the workflow will trigger the email.  I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with cascading filtering, I used it in past:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39842.cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ill just post my opinion on how to simplify the solution specially that spd workflows are very messy to work on. I'll just put it by bullets and think of it as a workflow action/setup.

1. The workflow trigger needs to be on create and on modify
2. on list item create/modify, wf will query items from list B depending on a column in list A (you can reference rest api filters [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests), and usage samples [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-selecting-filtering-sortin/)), so basically it will filter and get all the items that has the same car values
3. Loop the items from step 2 with 'foreach' action, then send an email, feed the column that has the email value from list B.

Hope the 3 steps concepts helps! Happy Learning!